# Can we prove that $A^T(B + C)A = A^TBA + A^TCA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think this might just be a dumb, obvious question. We know the distributive properties of matrix multiplication for matrices **A**, **B**, **C**, and **D** as:

$A(B + C) = AB + AC$ and $(B + C)D = BD + BC$

Then, say we have a 2xN matrix **A** and two 2x2 matrices **B** and **C**, can we use the 2 statements above to prove that:

$A^T(B + C)A = A^TBA + A^TCA$ ?

I've tried a set of numerical values and these seem to hold true. Not sure if there is any matrix law that could be used as a counterargument or not.

Comment: More generally: $$D(A+B)C=DAC+DBC.$$

Comment: Yes, it is just the distributive law used twice in a row.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I guess I was making it more complicated than I should.

Answer (score 1):

More generally: $$D(A+B)C=DAC+DBC.$$

By the distributive law:

$$D(A+B)=DA+DB$$

Then multiply on the right by $C:$

$$D(A+B)C=(DA+DB)C=DAC+DBC$$

again by the distributive law.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was a very simple and effective way to prove it.